# toUpperCase not working in JavaScript with items in an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I cant figure out why this is returning as an error.

> item.Question.toUpperCase is not a function

I get this error in my expo application with react but no errors are thrown in the console

Error:

> TypeError: item.Question.toUpperCase is not a function. 
>   in `item.Question.toUpperCase()` `item.Question.toUpperCase` is undefined

I tried creating new variables as

```
var Question = item.Question.toUpperCase()
```

But that didn't seem to work so here is the full code

```
else if(item.Title == undefined){
        const itemData = `${item.Question.toUpperCase()} ${item.answer.toUpperCase()} ${item.keyword.toUpperCase()}`;
        const textData = search.toUpperCase();

        return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
```

item is an object in which Question is a string

Thank you

Edit:
So after some logging I found this area to be giving the error:

```
console.log(item.keyword,item.Title)
        console.log(typeof item.Question, item.Question)
        const itemData = `${item.Title.toUpperCase()} ${item.Question.toUpperCase()} ${item.answer.toUpperCase()} ${item.keyword.toUpperCase()}`;
        const textData = search.toUpperCase();
        console.log(typeof itemData,typeof textData)
```

when logging item.Question and the type I got number and NaN which is odd because from my database it should be pulling the string "this is a strng10"
All the other calls to the database seem to be working fine. They give the correct type for item.Question as String.

So I guess the problem I'm trying to solve is how the string is being converted to a number that is NaN?

Comment: `.toUpperCase()` apply only on string values

Comment: what's the result of `console.log(itemData, textData)` - all upper case?

Comment: What is `item` and `Question` here? Please provide full info when asking a question. Also, read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @palaѕн I hope this is enough clarification, sorry about that.

Comment: @gorak Sorry I should have clarified, Question inside of each item object is a string

Comment: @JaromandaX It is logging everything as uppercase

Comment: "_item.Question.toUpperCase is not a function_" this is not possible if `Question` is a string. Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) to show the issue happening.

Comment: @palaѕн when logging item.Question it returns it as type String however it also says that item.Question.toUpperCase is undefined in item.Question.toUpperCase. I realized that the rest of the error message might be useful but if not I will try to give a demo.

Comment: so, it's logging everything in uppercase? how is this even possible if you are getting an error?

Comment: @JaromandaX the error is item.Question.toUpperCase is undefined, is it not reading it as the .toUpperCase() method?

Comment: but you just said everything is console.log ing in upper case - but it can't log it if the statement before it throws an error - is this code in a loop of some sort?

Comment: @JaromandaX in the console no errors are thrown but in my Expo react app it throws the error. This code is also part of a search method that loops through all of the objects in the array

Comment: `answer` and `keyword` are lowercased, are you sure it's `item.Question` with a capital Q in your object(s)?

Comment: perhaps your loop is wrong

Comment: @DrewReese Yes I double checked but I had pushed into the dataarray with "Question" I just was not very consistent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after logging all the way back to my call to the database I found an extra + before getting the question, removing that fixed the issue. So sorry for wasting all of your time.

The issuse was inside the object:

```
Question: + childData.Question
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work on my end. Are you certain you're passing the correct datatypes?

```
let item = {
  Question: "test",
  Title: undefined,
  Answer: "thing",
  Keyword: "wow"
}

if (item.Title === undefined) {
  const itemData =
      `${item.Question.toUpperCase()} ${item.Answer.toUpperCase()} ${item.Keyword.toUpperCase()}`
  itemData
}
```

Console returns `"TEST THING WOW"`

Comment: I ran console.log(typeof itemData,typeof textData) and got String String so they should be correct

Comment: I second throwing this into a demo sandbox for visibility.

We'll need to see the values and types of the props on objects "item" and "search" to help much more.

Comment: You mentioned this is part of a loop, I would add some console logs into the loop before and after assignment of the new variable to see if you're getting any changes in the objects properties.